# MySQL where field1 is equal to field2 plus integer

Tags: mysql

I have two int fields in mysql table say `apples` and `bananas`. I would like to select all rows where apples=bananas+2 (resulting 2,4 or 122,124 or 1020,1022 etc). 
I tried `"SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE apples=bananas+2"`, `"SELECT *,bananas+2 AS bans FROM tablename WHERE apples=bans"` but returns empty and "no bans field" error consecutively. Any ideas?

Comment: Show the ddl please

Answer (score 2):

If you need rows where `apples = bananas + 2`, you probably want to put `where apples = bananas - 2`, or `where bananas = apples + 2`.

Also, remember to check your fields' type, because if they are `unsigned` you better use the addition rather than a subtraction that could cause an error.